# Unique combinations with elements from a set

Tags: combinatorics, computational-mathematics

I am not a mathematician per say, so please forgive me if I am not using the correct terminology. 
I have the following question:
I have a set of 6 elements, i.e `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`. Now, I would like to find out a general formula for the number of combinations if I chose `k` out of `n` elements to compare them. In other words how many iteration will I need to cycle from 1 through 6. Note: `(1,2) = (2,1)` i.e without repetitions. For instance, if I choose three elements at a time, I will need only 5 iterations to compare the elements:

```
1.  (1,2), (1,3), (1,4)
2.  (1,5), (1,6), (2,3)
3.  (2,4), (2,5), (2,6)
4.  (3,4), (3,5), (3,6)
5.  (4,5), (4,6), (5,6)
```

If I choose 4 elements at a time, I will have:

```
1.  (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5)
2.  (1,6), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5)
3.  (2,6), (3,4), (3,5), (3,6)
4.  (4,5), (4,6), (5,6)
```

In this case it took 3 full iterations and one partial e.g, total=3.75 iterations.
So, I have been trying to come up with a formula for the number of full and partial iterations. 
Hopefully my questions makes sense, and you could help!

Comment: You have ${6 \choose 2}=15$.  Are you asking for a formula for $\frac{15}{3}=5$ and $\frac{15}{4}=3.75$ etc.?

Comment: @Henry Exactly!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$ ways to choose a set of $k$ distinct elements from a set of $n$ distinct elements, which is what you have.  So, the number of $k$ comparisons is $$\frac{n!}{kk!(n-k)!}.$$

Comment: The last formula is what I was looking for. I am aware of the first formula but it never occurred to me to divide by one more `k`.